# Unknown type name (C++) JUCE

Tags: c++, juce

I have an issue with my cpp file where I have written a component code into my header file. But my CPP file could not read it for some reason and it shows as unknown type name. I have also include the header file into the cpp file. What am I missing?

[cpp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ap7k.png) [header file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCgQp.png)

Comment: Please post code as text within the question.

Comment: Try adding the namespace juce, ie. juce::Component.